# docker-compose up load build definition error

Tags: docker

I am developing a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like so:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
 web-app: 
   build: ./my-frontend-app.Dockerfile
   ports:
     - "4200:4200"
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read
> dockerfile: error from sender: walk
> /Users/daniel/My_Projects/my-frontend-app/my-frontend-app.Dockerfile:
> not a directory ERROR: Service 'web-app' failed to build : Build
> failed

So it failed to build because it cannot locate the directory my Dockerfile is in?

Comment: The argument to `build:` is a _directory_ name; usually the Dockerfile is named exactly `Dockerfile` in that directory.  Is that the filesystem layout you have on your host?

Comment: @DavidMaze, ahh, so there is more than one `Dockerfile`, so the convention with this app has been to give the Dockerfile some specifying name and then use `Dockerfile` as a sort of ending extension. What would be the best way to do this in light of having more than one Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Compose [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) with just a string, that string is interpreted as a *directory* name, and the Dockerfile is assumed to be in a file named exactly `Dockerfile` in that directory.  There is an extended form of `build:` that lets you specify a [`dockerfile:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dockerfile) within the build context.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
 web-app: 
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: my-frontend-app.Dockerfile
```

(If you can use all default options – you can use the default `dockerfile: Dockerfile` and do not need `args:` or any other special build-time options – I tend to prefer the short `build: ./directory-name/` syntax, but it won't work in your case when you have multiple Dockerfiles.)